# Polymer component dispatching event in Safari

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x

I have a custom Polymer 2+ component like so:

```
<my-button id="my-button"></my-button>
```

*Inside* the component, I have this block of code in several places (on `ready()`, on a mouse press, etc.) for testing:

```
this.dispatchEvent(new Event('test'));
this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('testCustom', {detail: {hey:'hey'}, bubbles:true, composed: true}));
```

In Chrome, *both* of these can be caught and logged in the below listener that implements the button:

```
var myEl = document.getElementById('my-button')

myEl.addEventListener('test', function(){
   console.log('test reached');
})

myEl.addEventListener('testCustom', function(ev){
   console.log('test custom reached');
})
```

However, in Safari 11, on macOS Sierra, they are not. [CustomEvent](https://caniuse.com/#search=CustomEvent) should be supported in Safari, am I doing something silly here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I figured it out, but the answer is bizarre.  If I change this line:

```
var myEl = document.getElementById('my-button')
```

to

```
var myEl = document.querySelector('my-button')
```

it will all of a sudden work in Safari.  I have no explanation as to why, there shouldn't be a naming conflict as `getElementById()` should still be able to select the element.